# Information about the Vilna Siddur

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book

I am looking for information on the Vilna Siddur.
What is the vilna/vilnis Siddur?(for example how is it different than a regular Ashkenazi Siddur)
Who authored it?
And is there a copy online?

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/search/?s=siddur&teacher=80165&sort=1

Comment: Wasn't it put together by one of the niturei karta?

Comment: It looks like Mishnah Berurah vomit, according to most graphic designers (I agree with them) and it is likely too recent to be online, yet. If you're interested in purchasing it, it's not difficult to find

Comment: Whoever wrote the stuff in it never mentions his/their name(s). They have a P.O. box in upstate NY, and they also have an address in Meah Shearim, so יש לדון on the niturei karta claim. I personally love the font and how it's organized. Unique aspects of the siddur are the big introductions to each section of the siddur, like psukei dzimra, krias shema, shmoneh esrei, etc., these have concise halachos as well as explanations of the ideas. Another thing is the לקט באורים which brings down mareh mekomos for psukim, and sometimes short explanations phrase by phrase.

Comment: I think they pride themselves on the accuracy of their nusach, like fixing maskilish edits. The regular siddur has everything you need for the whole year except for Yamim Noraim, like most other siddurim. They also have a machzor for Yamim Noraim (separate volumes for R'H and Y"K) which is done is pretty much the same way. Although the machzor has a ton, and I really mean an absolute ton of piyutim (which they speak about in their hakdama in the front of the machzor, ע"ש). I found the machzor in Next to the Mir, and I've seen it online, but I've never seen anyone using it ever.